# SQL: How to make a join query with only having the "largest" entry of any "type"?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables: Table eventtypes and Table events with one-to-many relation. Every event has a timestamp. Now I would like to have an SQL query that returns me every eventtype + its corresponding event with the latest timestamp (which I can guarantee to be unique in this case).

I'm not completely sure how this is supposed to be done with SQL directly the correct way. So far, I used something like this:

```
select * from eventtypes left join 
(
    select events.* from events right join 
    (
        select max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp from events groupby eventtypeid
    ) maxtimestamps
    on events.timestamp = maxtimestamps.maxtimestamp
) lastevents
on eventtypes.id = lastevents.eventtypeid
```

(Excuse me for the *. This is not production, I just wrote this from my head)
These two inner selects always made me wonder if that is the correct way. I always thought, there should be something like this:

```
select max(timestamp), corresponding(id), corresponding(name), ... 
from events groupby eventtypeid
```

I think a function like corresponding() does not exist. Why? Wouldn't this be possible to be implemented fast in the sql server than executing the 2 selects and the join? Or is there some other method to do this efficiently in sql? Or is it already efficient?

Comment: Thanks to the answerers! Both answers actually helped me with my question, both show ways to do this, and the discussion around them also helped. So it's hard to choose from the two answers. I'll just choose Tomek's, because he has less points. :D Sorry ypercube. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the timestamp is guaranteed to be unique (and only when that's true) this query will do:

```
select 
      eventtypes.*,
      events.*
from 
    events A INNER JOIN eventtypes B ON A.eventtypeid=b.id
WHERE 
    A.timestamp IN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM events GROUP BY eventtypeid)
```

Comment: You mean `SELECT A.*, B.* ...` but yes, that would work, too!

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Would something like this also work: where (A.timestamp, A.id) in (select max(timestamp), eventtypeid from events group by eventtypeid) ? Or is there a different syntax for that?

Comment: @marc40000: no you can't use "in" operator against 2 columns

Comment: @TOmek: I think you can in some DBMS (in Postgres and DB2 if i'm not wrong). It's valid SQL syntax but not implemented in most DBMS.

Comment: @ypercube: I'm thinking in the context of MS Sql Server, but concrete engine wasn't mention, so yes I was to fast in that statement

Answer (score 2):

Your query can be simplified to:

```
select 
      eventtypes.*,
      events.*
from 
    eventtypes 
  left join 
      events 
    join 
      (
          select
                eventtypeid,                             --- this line added 
                max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp 
          from events 
          group by eventtypeid
      ) maxtimestamps
    on  events.timestamp = maxtimestamps.maxtimestamp
    AND events.eventtypeid = maxtimestamps.eventtypeid   --- and this
  on eventtypes.id = lastevents.eventtypeid
```

The lines were added because your version may show incorrect results, if the `timestamp` is not Unique.

---

In many DBMS, there are funcions called "analytic" or "windowing" that can get you the same results, in the way you describe:

```
SELECT
      et.*,
      e.*
FROM eventtypes et
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT 
            events.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eventtypeid 
                              ORDER BY timestamp DESC )
              AS RowNum
      FROM events
    ) e
    ON e.eventtypeid = et.eventtypeid
    AND e.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Ah. I had a mistake in my inner select. You did what I meant directly, so I corrected my post as well. Apart from that, the key point of my question is this max an group by thing. With a theoretical corresponding() function, your query can be rewritten with only one select by doing select eventtypes.*, max(events.timestamp), corresponding(events.*) from eventtypes left join events on {what you did} eventtypes groupby events.id Since I think a corresponding() function does not exist (am I wrong?), is what you wrote actually the thought way to do that query in SQL?

Comment: Initially I thought you have a bug there (without added those 2 lines) but since the timestamp is guaranteed to be unique those 2 lines are not required.

Comment: @Tomek: If the timestmap is Unique, they can be omitted. But I would prefer this, in both cases. It will work if the Unique constraint is removed in the future and second, it will use only one index: `(eventtypeid, timestamp)`, both for the Group By and the Joins.

Comment: @ypercube: totally agree, if there is a chance that in the future constraint might be violated then your query is safer

Comment: @you both, if you don't add those two lines, does it need more then 1 index?

Comment: @ypercube, in what way exactly is your first query simpler? Reading wise? Or also more efficient? Or is actually hard to say because we can't really tell what the query optimizers do before they run the query?

Comment: It has only one subquery (yours has 2 levels of nested subqueries). I also find it easier to read without parenthesis (or with less).

Comment: @marc40000: about the index needed without the 2 lines, you can try the query in your DBMS (which you haven't told us yet!) and see the execution plans with various indexes. I would guess it would also need an index on `timestamp` for the join.

Comment: Regarding the DBMS I'm using: Right now, I have this question with a project using Microsoft SQL Server, but I have encountered this before on mysql and access, so my question is more generic than DBMS specific.

Comment: @ypercube: greatest-n-per-group is a great tag by the way :)